# Heavy duty Excavation aka Stone to Mud in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic

I seem to be at a loss here. Either I can't find a spell that works here or I am not seeing it. What method would a wizard (or other spellcaster for that matter) use to excavate a part of a dungeon? To create new rooms in a dungeon or something like this?

I seem to recall that there used to be a spell called "stone to mud" in my earlier D&D days. This does not seem to exist anymore. Is there a replacement I am not seeing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the release of the Elemental Evil Player's Companion, there is now a spell that does exactly what you're looking for. *Transmute Rock* is a 5th level spell available to Wizards and Druids, one of the uses of which is to turn a 40-foot cube of stone into mud.

The *Stone Shape* spell allows you to, well, shape stone, but only a 5-foot cube at a time. (So I suppose this is an option, just a very slow one.)

The *Disintegrate* spell can disintegrate stone, but only a 10-foot cube at a time.

The *Move Earth* spell allows you to alter terrain in up to 40-foot cubes, but only dirt and soft earth, no stone. So if there is a natural cave system, you could remove all the dirt from it, but you can't create rooms in solid stone.

And finally, there is the usual standby. A correctly worded *Wish* will of course achieve whatever you need it to. (Depending on how nice your DM is.)

However, there is another option: *Dominate Monster*. An Umber Hulk can burrow freely through solid stone, leaving a tunnel in its wake.

> ***Tunneler.*** The umber hulk can burrow through solid rock at half its burrowing speed and leaves a 5 foot-wide, 8-foot-high tunnel in its wake.

Conveniently, the Umber Hulk has a Wisdom saving throw bonus of +0, so by the time you can cast *Dominate Monster*, it should be highly likely to succeed. All you need to do is find an Umber Hulk!

Finding an Umber Hulk could be quite tricky. A *Scrying* spell will let you look at an Umber Hulk, which in turn will let you cast *Locate Creature*. However, *Locate Creature* only has a radius of 1000 feet, so it will require some luck for this strategy to succeed.

An alternative is to use *Scrying*, then *Teleport*. This only has a 25% chance of success, *unless* you *Teleport* while *Scrying*, in which case it has a 75% chance of success. Obviously this won't tell you where an Umber Hulk actually is, but having *Teleport*-ed to one you should be able to Dominate it and then *Teleport* it and yourself back to the site you wish to excavate.

Another solution, by far the simplest despite me not coming up with it till now, is just to *Shapechange* into an Umber Hulk and do the digging yourself. Much less risky.